# How to disable buttons in site that uses local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

here is my `html`

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr style="background-color: white">
        <th> <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Name </th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Particular</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Unit</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Quantity</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>From</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Date</th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>TAKE actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>COMB</td>
        <td>fasionable comb</td>
        <td>SVP</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Bindibhatt1</td>
        <td>2014-03-22 18:15:34 UTC
        </td><td>
          <form action="/requisitions/2" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input class="pos" data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit" value = "po" ></div></form>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

AND MY `jquery`

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $(".pos").click(function(e){
        debugger;
        localStorage.setItem("visited" + $(this).closest("tr").index(), true);
        $(this).css("color", "red"); // visited
    });

    for(var i = 0, len = $(".pos").length; i < len; i++){

        if(localStorage.getItem("visited" + i)){

            $(".pos:eq(" + i + ")").css("color", "white"); // visited

        }else
        {
            $(".pos:eq(" + i + ")").css("color", "black"); // not visited
        }
    }
});
```

I want the button which is clicked to be `disabled` and the `html` should be `generated` from `po`.

Comment: button value is `po` after l=click it should be changed to `generated`

Comment: In input tag you have written 'class="po"' inplace of 'class="pos"'.

Comment: Which button value is `po`? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button with:

```
for(var i = 0, len = $("tr.pos").length; i < len; i++) {

    if(localStorage.getItem("visited" + i)) {
        $("tr.pos").eq(i).css("color", "white").prop('disabled', true).val('generated'); // visited
    } else {
        $("tr.pos").eq(i).css("color", "black"); // not visited
    }
}
```

You need the more specific selector `tr.pos` because you also have `input.pos` in your DOM (you didn't show that in your question).

Comment: it os on click i want the effect after visit..you can see in my `jquery`

Comment: I've changed it to set the property and value in the `for` loop.

Comment: It is working but only `even` rows..rest have no effect

Comment: I can't think of a reason for that. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: if you can make fiddle please healp me

Comment: I'm not going to make a fiddle for you. You make the fiddle and then I'll try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you have both `<tr class="pos">` and `<input type="button" class="pos">`. So `$(".pos:eq(N)")` is getting the `tr` when `N` is even, the `input` when `N` is odd.

Comment: See the updated answer for the fix to this. Or you could use different classes for the input and tr -- I'm not sure why you would want them in the same class.

Comment: it is working in my fiddle but not in my application...can you fix it by team viewer

Comment: Use the Javascript debugger like I did, so you can see what's happening in your code. I'm not spending any more time on this question, I think I've given you enough help that you should be able to finish by yourself if you're at all competent.